# How Class/Static Methods get invoked

Tags: java, class, oop, object

While reading [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) I came to know that, class methods are invoked on an object which got the same name as class.

I found objective-c also does a similar thing from a [blog](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html). Here Classes happens to be instances of meta-classes.

As another major Object Oriented language i would love to know how Java implements/achieve this.

**Edit**

I appreciate the answers from everyone. But my question wasn't about how to invoke a class method. As many answers were answering that. Apologies if my question was not well framed or it gave you a wrong idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java language, static methods are invoked on the class instead of an object e.g. `System.currentTimeMillis`. So conceptually this is very similar to Ruby, ObjC, Smalltalk, etc.

Unlike Ruby and Objective C, there is no object instance that those methods get invoked upon: The Java bytecode has a special bytecode instruction that invokes the static method; this bytecode instruction does not use an object pointer from the stack:

```
INVOKESTATIC "java/lang/System" "currentTimeMillis" "()J"
```

When using reflection, this special handling of static methods is represented by the fact that you don't need to specify an object that the method is called upon. Instead, you can supply `null` as the target of the call.

Answer (score 2):

In Java We can call static methods with class name.like

```
ClassName.staticMethod(args);
```

Keep in mind that they are class level methods and variables and beyond to any object , So thats why they are called by class name.
You can see its live demo by JVM when compiling any java program with error because `main` is also a static method

```
public class TradingSystem {

    String description = "electronic trading system";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        description = "commodity trading system";
    }
}
```

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field description

```
  at TradingSystem.main(TradingSystem.java:8)
```

Also see [10 points about static keyword in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/11/static-keyword-method-variable-java.html) 
 **AND** Here is [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

Refer the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2):

> A class method is always invoked without reference to a particular object.

When the Java virtual machine invokes a class method, it selects the method to invoke based on the type of the object reference, which is always known at compile-time, static (early) binding.

Answer (score 1):

> Static methods, which have the static modifier in their declarations, should be invoked with the class name, without the need for creating an instance of the class, as

```
ClassName.methodName(args)
```

moreover a  static method is called by prefixing it with a class name, eg, Math.max(i,j);. Curiously, it can also be qualified with an object, which will be ignored, but the class of the object will be used.

[**Official Docs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

static method or variables are invoked using the class itself.
e.g.

if you have a static member as `public static Integer age` in class `Employee`, then you invoke it using `Employee.age`

same goes with methods also. e.g. `Employee.paySalary();`

Let us consider an example.

```
public class StaticDemo {


    public static void methodToPrintSomething(){
        System.out.println("printing any crap");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StaticDemo.methodToPrintSomething();

        StaticDemo obj = new StaticDemo();
        obj .methodToPrintSomething();


    }

}
```

Here method is called using `obj.methodToPrintSomething()`. Another interesting thing you can find is the statement `obj.methodToPrintSomething()`. We are creating an object to call a static method, but that does not mean we are calling `methodToPrintSomething()` on the object. As it is `static`, internally the statement `obj.methodToPrintSomething()` will be treated as `StaticDemo.methodToPrintSomething()`

Answer (score 0):

In java static methods belongs to the class rather than objects of that class. So, static methods are called by className as:

```
ClassName.staticMethod();
```